# How does capture group nesting affect group numbers?

Tags: c#, regex

Can I have a regex like this where I have a group within a group?  If so, in .NET which is group 1 and which group 2?

```
^(abc(def))$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group that starts first (as read from left to right) is always lower numbered<sup>1</sup>. In this case the "outer" group is #1 and the "inner" group is #2.

Consider using [*Named Matched Subexpressions (aka named groups)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) to avoid confusion - at least in more complex cases:

```
^(?<outer>abc(?<inner>def))$
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The wording from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#matched_subexpression):

> Captures that use parentheses are numbered automatically from left to right based on the order of the opening parentheses in the regular expression, starting from one.

Comment: irreguardless?  What kind of word is that!